# Why does Entity Framework 6 update the IDs of objects in my Related Entity collections?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have an object:

```
public class Eoi {

    // Generated by database
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    // Not 'virtual', want to force eager loading
    public IList<Document> Docs { get; set; }
}
```

This object has a 1:1 relationship with a Person:

```
public class Person {

    // Generated by database
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    // Not virtual, want to force eager loading
    public Eoi MyEoi { get; set; }
}
```

Document is defined as :

```
public class Document {

    // Generated by database
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; } // ... and other simple string properties, stripped for brevity
}
```

Whenever I load a `Person` and update their `Person.MyEoi`, and call `Context.SaveChangesAsync()` in EF6, the `Id`s of the `Documents` get replaced, and the Entity Framework Profiler shows that the old Documents get deleted, new ones get generated and saved that are **IDENTICAL**, WITH THE EXCEPTION OF THE `Id`. Does anybody know why Entity Framework 6 does this or how to stop it ?

UPDATE: The code that does this (paraphrased for brevity, all relevant parts included):

```
Expression<Func<Person, bool>> expression = p => p.Id == someId;
Expression<Func<TData, object>>[] fields = { p => p.MyEoi, p => p.MyEoi.Documents };

IQueryable<TData> queryable = this.EntitySet.Where(expression);

IQueryable<TData> aggregate = fields.Aggregate(queryable, (total, current) => total.Include(current));

Person person = aggregate.ToList().AsEnumerable().Single();

// ASP.NET MVC Controller bit:
this.TryUpdateModel(person.MyEoi, null, null, "Id,Documents".Split(','));

person.ModifiedAt = DateTimeOffset.Now;
person.Modifier = modifier;

// SOME OTHER SNIPPETS THAT MODIFY THE person.MyEoi field

await this.Context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that updates the EoI?

Comment: Code has been added that's representative of the problem.